# How to show different input data in model dialog?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, modal-dialog

I made a template form with input fields. I want to show some of these input field data in a modal dialog. I was able to send one value to the modal dialog, but I am thinking of using one reusable modal component.

The HTML Code:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div style="width: 10rem">
      <app-editable-input [text]="foodModel.standardName" (onUpdate)="foodModel.standardName = $event"></app-editable-input>
    </div>
    <mat-icon style="margin-left: 0.5rem; margin-top: 0.6rem; font-size: 2rem;cursor: pointer;" (click)="openDialog()">language</mat-icon>
  </div>
<table class="table-details w-100">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Carbohydrates</th>
    <th>Fats</th>
    <th>Protein</th>
    <th>Calories</th>
    <th>Lang</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let food of foodModel.servings; let i = index"> <!-- 'as' assigned serving. Donot use 'as'. -->
    <td>{{ food.id }}</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <app-editable-input [text]="food.localisedName | head" (onUpdate)="food.localisedName= $event"></app-editable-input>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <app-editable-input [text]="food.carbs" [unit]="'gms'"></app-editable-input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <app-editable-input [text]="food.fats" [unit]="'gms'"></app-editable-input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <app-editable-input [text]="food.protein" [unit]="'gms'"></app-editable-input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="margin-left: 1rem;">{{ food.calories }} kcals</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <mat-icon style="margin-left: 0.6rem;" (click)="openDialog()">language</mat-icon>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="boolean">
        <mat-icon>lens</mat-icon>
        Active
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <mat-icon style="margin-left: 0.5rem;" (click)="onClickDelete(i)">delete</mat-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the above you can see `(click)="openDialog()"`  has been called twice. I want the values of the both the click events when they are clicked to be showed in the same modal dialog. Not simultaneously, but one replacing other.

The TS code:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalAllComponent } from '../modal/modal-all/modal-all.component';

export interface FoodModel {
  standardName: string;
  localisedName: {
    code: string;
    title: string;
    value: string;
  }[];
  ratingInfo?: {
    rating: number;
    title: string;
  };
  servings: Serving[];
};

interface Serving {
  id?: number;
  standardName: string;
  localisedName: {
    lang: string;
    value: string;
  }[];
  carbs: number;
  protein: number;
  fats: number;
  calories:number;
  langs: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-food-details',
  templateUrl: './food-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./food-details.component.scss']
})
export class FoodDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  name!:any

  foodModel: FoodModel = {
    standardName: '',
    localisedName: [],
    servings: []
  };

  constructor(private router: Router, private dialog:MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onClickAddServing(): void {
    const serving: Serving = {
      standardName: '',
      localisedName: [
        {
          lang: 'en',
          value: ''
        }
      ],
      carbs: 0,
      protein: 0,
      fats: 0,
      calories:0,
      langs: 'en, fr, fr-CA'
    };
    this.foodModel.servings.push(serving);

    //const val = serving.localisedName.map(i => i.value)
  }

  onClickDelete(index: number) {
    this.foodModel.servings.splice(index, 1);
  }

  back() {
    this.router.navigate(['food-content']);
  }

  openDialog(){
  /*   let data = {
      msg:"message from food-details"
    } */
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalAllComponent, {
      width: '14.5rem',
      data:{ name: this.foodModel.standardName}
    })
  }
}
```

This the app-editable-input HTML:

```
<div class="edit-container">
  <p class="edit-input d-flex align-items-center pl-1 pr-1 w-100" [ngStyle]="{'font-size': textSize ?? '2rem'}" *ngIf="!edit" (click)="edit = true">
    <span style="min-width: 6rem;height: 3rem; padding: 0.8rem;" class="flex-grow-1">{{ text }}{{ unit }}</span>
    <span class="ml-2"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></span>
  </p>
  <div *ngIf="edit">
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="editedText" (blur)="onInputBlur();edit = false;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the app-editable-input ts:

```
  @Input() text: string | number = '';
  @Input() textSize: string = '1rem';
  editedText: string | number = '';
  @Input() unit:string = '';
  @Output() onUpdate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  edit: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setDefaults();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.setDefaults();
  }

  setDefaults() {
    this.editedText = this.text;
  }

  onInputBlur() {
    this.onUpdate.emit(this.editedText);
    this.text = this.editedText;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to pass the whole model into the modal (and reuse the modal for other models) or do you want to use the modal only for this model, but only one of its properties at once and don't know how to differentiate which property is currently being displayed?

Comment: The second one. There is only one model, but I want to show different properties of that `model` in one `modal` based on which button is clicked. The best way to describe it is, there is one textarea and based on the which button i click the proprties of that model is displayed respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to give the modal-component an input `prop: string` which you pass as part of `data`. Then, subscribe to the closing event of `dialogRef` (this should also pass out that prop again) and then you can do something like `this.foodModel[prop] = newVal` (potentially needs type casting).

Bracket notating works like dot-notation, but with a string, e.g. `this.foodModel.standardName` is equivalent to `this.foodModel['standardName']`.

Edit:
A bit more of an example on how to open the dialog and get the results (incomplete and not necassarily correct syntax):

```
// open from template like (click)="openDialog('standardName')"
openDialog(propName: keyof FoodModel){  
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalAllComponent, {
    width: '14.5rem',
    data:{ 
      prop: propName,
      value: this.foodModel[propName]
    }
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) =>
    this.foodModel[result.prop] = result.value;
  );
}
```

In the dialog something like this:

```
export class YourDialog {
  prop: keyof FoodModel;
  value: string | number;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {prop: string, value: string | number}) { 
    this.prop = this.data.prop;
    this.value = this.data.prop;
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close({prop: this.prop, value: this.value});
  }
}
```

Docs for MatDialog: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Would you mind giving me one small example? Its only 2 months since I started working with angular. I am very new to this

Comment: I added a rough (incomplete) example to give an idea.

Comment: I tried your thing I was getting this error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FoodModel'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FoodModel'.ts(7053)` @Gunnar

Comment: I encountered the error in `value: this.foodModel[propName]`

Comment: Ah, my bad. `propName: string` is not specific enough for typescript (could be any string, so potentially not being a valid prop of the model). Changed it to `openDialog(propName: keyof FoodModel)`, also the type in the dialog (and whereever else you'd need to type it).